# java HmacSHA1 hash does not match with swift (IOS)

Tags: java, swift

Java version:

```java
public static byte[] computeSignature(String algorithm, byte[] data, byte[] sharedSecret) {
    try {
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(sharedSecret, algorithm);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        mac.init(secretKey);
        return Base64.encode(mac.doFinal(data));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // 
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        //
    }
}
```

Swift version:

```swift
func hmac(key: String) -> String {
    let inputData: NSData = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    let keyData: NSData = key.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!

    let algorithm = HMACAlgorithm.SHA1
    let digestLen = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
    let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(digestLen)

    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA1), keyData.bytes, keyData.length, inputData.bytes, inputData.length, result)
    let data = NSData(bytes: result, length: digestLen)
    result.destroy()
    return data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
}
```

Here is the javascript version that uses CryptoJs which produce same hmacsha1 hash as java code: https://jsfiddle.net/333VW/

Comment: I had to make some minor changes to your  `hmac()` method to make it compile in Xcode 6.3, but then `"Message".hmac("Secret Passphrase")` produces exactly the same result `6Q9xMpXqTMBskskkhpb/r8XQH68=` as the JavaScript fiddle. What result do you get?

Comment: @MartinR, I was having unwanted space in message, and thus was getting different hash, I verified that this code works perfectly.  Thank You Very Much for looking and confirming ! btw, You r awesome !

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and accept it later..

Comment: @user1803551, not sure how do I do that.

Comment: You answer your own question just like any other question. You then need to wait 48 hours until you can accept it.